# Python version >= 3.4 do not deliver a working PIP utility. It seems impossible to add it afterward

Tags: python, pip

Python3.6 installs PIP but it is unreachable as it is installed. There is no code which will invoke in the state that it is installed. I have read every advice possible on this issue without success!

Not even the upgrade will work...

user@loco:~/devstack$ pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Python3.6 installs PIP but it is unreachable as it is installed.  if there is a way to trigger the installed PIP it is a mystery to me!  After much agony, I have found a way to update that installed version, which is PIP version 9.xxx. Here is what worked for me.

```
root@bx:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages # python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

That command created a PIP which now works properly from any location on my FreeBSD server!  Delivered by the Python 3.6 install the PIP only works by invoking Python first.  Once invoked that way it updates to version 9 with the latest.  In my case, it was version 19.xxx.  What is interesting is that it immediately became global and accessible from everywhere, so no need to play with the ports etc.

Clearly, the tools installed simply do not work properly, as installed with Python3.6. The only way to run them is to invoke Python and the desired python files as you can see in the command issued.  Once the update is called, however, the new PIP works globally without having to invoke Python3.6 explicitly...

P.S.  Keep in mind that if your command "python" invokes python2.7 you will not be able to complete your upgrade.  For that you will have to mess with your ports or invoke the command I supplied with Python3.6 or whatever invokes your version 3.x python.